# Global CSS Color Scheme / Skin

Tags: css, colors, themes, skinning

I am constucting a site using CSS that needs to be skinnable / brandable. In technical terms, for each "brand" I have a set of five color values in a database.

What I want to do is construct CSS files so that the color scheme of the entire site is unified and the colors are reused, so I can change the value in one place and it changes the entire site. The concept would look like this:

.SiteBaseColor {color:sienna;}

p {font-size: 50; color:SiteBaseColor;}

Is there a way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Further to @Pekka's comment, I'll explain *how*. Just in case. Next to each answer offered to your question there is an outline of a tick-mark. Click on the tick-mark besides the answer that you feel **best answers** your question. If **no** answers work for you, **edit the question** to better-explain your problem(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to investigate the preprocessor choice ( my favourite for this case) I agree with Pekka, but my choice would be [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) which, i think, is powerful than less..

Using a css preprocessor you can write one sass file ad than compile it in 6 different css files just changing color variables each time...

But, if you've to pull the colors from a database maybe it simpler to use php snippets in the css file..

Answer (score 5):

Why don't just write 6 css files? One for all the content (without the scheme-color) and one per color.
Then you just include the one you need.

The same if you generate it by php, just make 5 different entry-point for schemas and include the right one...

Comment: I wanted to avoid this so that I don't have to change 6 style sheets if I change non-color related attributes.

Comment: That part should go in the main css files... Only the theme-related definitions should go in the 5 theme-css.

Comment: This is much more in line with how CSS was designed to be used.  Hence the 'Cascading' : layering one stylesheet upon another. LESS and xCSS are neat applications, but they are not really necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, CSS does not support variables. You would have to use a CSS pre-processor like [**Less**](http://lesscss.org/) or [**xCSS**](http://xcss.antpaw.org/), or use PHP snippets:

```
<? $ourColor = "#FF0000"; ?>

.....
div.content { color: <?php echo $ourColor; ?> }
```

Comment: Is there a .NET equivalent to these PHP snippets?

Comment: Depends on your language, it should be straightforward: Defining a variable and outputting it.